# Ubuntu Update Manager fails

Tags: package-management

I have Ubuntu desktop installed. Every time Update Manager runs it fails:

```
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnutls26/libgnutls26_2.12.14-5ubuntu3.6_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.79.10_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

I can ping and curl `91.189.88.149` just fine. Since it's returning 404, there is an active HTTP server on port 80. For some reason update-manager is requesting an invalid resource.

It's been failing to update for the last few months. Update Manager appears when I select "Updates Available..." from the gear icon/menu.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

Follow-up: Update Manager has been renamed to [Software Updater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Updater).

Comment: I don't know what `update-manager` is, but what does `apt-get update` give?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Update Manager is a GUI tool developed by Ubuntu that basically pops up, tells you to click to apply updates, and shows you the update transcript on request.

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion of Faheem's comment and [this post](https://code.google.com/p/winetricks/issues/detail?id=409), running `apt-get update` first solved the problem. Specifically `apt-get update` installed a bunch of updates, then Update Manager ran and also installed a bunch of updates.

Comment: Update Manager is a GUI frontend to `apt-get`, which is a command line tool. The behavior you're observing looks like a bug.

Comment: Frontends are of limited usefulness when it comes to package management. I recommend just using apt or aptitude directly.

Comment: But Update Manager updated something after apt-get, so it must be doing something extra.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. A couple of things I did resolved it.

I opened Update Manager, selected settings and unchecked 'unsupported updates'.  When I re-ran the updates the cache was updated and some updates got successfully loaded.  I was then prompted to reboot.

I attempted to run updates from Update Manager again and it failed, but this time I was prompted to fix a broken package via Synaptic Package Manager.

I fixed the broken package and now Update Manager works with no problems.